# How to convert to ISO-8859-1 data from api Facebook in php?

Tags: php, facebook, iso-8859-1

I need to convert the data retrived from api Facebook to ISO-8859-1 in php.

This is an example of output of the api facebook (look to description value)
I look that the php api facebook used this method

```
protected static function base64UrlDecode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
  }

{
   "id": "108012702561007",
   "name": "Sud Sound System",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Sud-Sound-System/108012702561007",
   "likes": 24904,
   "category": "Musician/band",
   "website": "http://www.sudsoundsystem.eu",
   "is_community_page": true,
   "description": "\u003cp>I \u003cb>Sud Sound System\u003c/b>",
   "parking": {
      "street": 0,
      "lot": 0,
      "valet": 0
   },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON defines that escaping syntax as an alternative to Unicode UTF-8 encoding.

A solution was suggested here: [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-char)

An explanation about that UTF-8 escaping format can be found here: [JSON character encoding - is UTF-8 well-supported by browsers or should I use numeric escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583562/json-character-encoding) (which points to the RFC: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).

In your case, you'll need to transform from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 afterwards (though imho you'd be better off using UTF-8 all along).