# Unicode values in strings are escaped when dumping to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, unicode

For example:

```
>>> print(json.dumps('růže'))
"r\u016f\u017ee"
```

(Of course, in the real program it's not just a single string, and it also appears like this in the file, when using `json.dump()`) I'd like it to output simply "růže" as well, how to do that?

Comment: As long as it can be parsed back into "růže", why does it matter what the json looks like?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583562/json-character-encoding?

Comment: Whoops, I wasn't aware of that, I probably should have checked it first. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pass the `ensure_ascii=False` argument to json.dumps:

```
>>> print(json.dumps('růže', ensure_ascii=False))
"růže"
```

Comment: This works! Except that since I was serializing and object, I had to convert the unicode strings with `.encode('utf-8')` first, otherwise it threw `UnicodeEncodeError` errors. Thanks!