# In Python how do I write characters such as ½ or ¼ to json file

Tags: python, json

Looking at similar questions here I thought I had this solved and it was fairly simple.  I am trying to write a line like:

"¼kg beef"

To a json file.  I am writing from an array of strings (lines).

lines is built from a long string(ingredients) with carriage returns.

```
ingredients = "__Name: 0: Cottage pie\n__scrape_schema\n__url:https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/cottage-pie\n3 tbsp olive oil\n1 ¼kg beef mince\n2 onions,finely chopped\n3 carrots,chopped\n"

lines=ingredients.split('\n')
```

I see the recommendation is to do something like this:

```
import json
data={}
with open('test.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as json_file: 
    for line in lines:
        json.dump(line, json_file)
```

I do not get an error message but in the json file I get the following note:

"*SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 25 of the JSON data*"

And the data written is:

" \u00bckg beef"

Here is the top of the json file showing both:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 25 of the JSON data
"__Name: 0: Cottage pie""__scrape_schema ""__url: [https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/cottage-pie""3](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/cottage-pie%22%223) tbsp olive oil""1 \u00bckg beef mince""2 onions,fin...

I am not trying to localize and I really need nothing more than handling the character fractions.  So I am not sure what else I should do?

Comment: what is `lines` - why do you write to file line by line?

Comment: lines is an array of strings.  I have updated my question.

Comment: please share `lines` or a subset of it

Comment: Where do you get the SyntaxError?

Comment: The "¼kg beef"  is a subset of lines -- ie, one line.

Comment: The Syntax error is written to the json file.

Comment: I thought "\u00bckg beef" was written to the json file? (and when I try this, it is the only thing written)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865180/unicode-values-in-strings-are-escaped-when-dumping-to-json-in-python

Comment: @jz_ It makes no sense whatsoever to write a json file line by line. All you need to do is `with open('test.json', 'w') as f: json.dump(lines, f)`.

Comment: No, both are written to the file.  Now in the question.  I have also added code to how lines is built.

Comment: I have added a short example of ingredients.  The for looped seemed to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that:

```
with open('test.json', 'w') as f: json.dump(lines, f)
```

solves the problem.  The for loop seemed to introduce a second problem that is no longer there.