# Apple Push Notification Service - use of £ and € characters in message text

Tags: ios, json, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm building a service to push out notifications to iOS devices over APNS.  Everything is working great, except for the fact that if the message text includes the £ (British Pound) or € (Euro) characters then the notification is not sent by APNS.  I don't think this is a JSON issue as they don't normally need escaping (I've tried escaping them anyway to no avail).  Is there something I need to do in order to support the whole character set?

Comment: I had a look around but could only find pieces on people struggling with a potential problem of not sending in UTF-8 format. They certainly were having the same problem with sending umlauts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the JSON ASCII escape for Unicode? Send `\u00A3` for £ and `\u20AC` for €.

[JSON character encoding - is UTF-8 well-supported by browsers or should I use numeric escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583562/json-character-encoding)