# Is this a correct practice to generate friendly URLs?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, friendly-url, seo

I'm generating url of AJAX call like I explain [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764391/is-my-way-the-best-practice-to-generate-a-url-of-ajax-calls). *(Please take a look of this post, is necesary to understand the actual).*

Some url has special chars so would be something like:

`http://myweb.com/ni%C3%B1o/pull%26bear/jacket%20shirt%20pants%20underwear%20hat/23`

And I want to create friendly URLs removing some chars and limiting the third parameter to have only three words maximum. The result will be like this:

`http://myweb.com/nino/pullbear/jacket-shirt-pants/23`

So the php will be able to know what parameters I'm passing I added a new colum in my database for each *VARCHAR* with the pretty url conversion. I explain, something like this:

```
ID  SEX   SEX_PRETTY  BAND       BRAND_PRETTY  DESCRIPTION                       DESCRIPTION_PRETTY   AGE
1   NIÑO  NINO        PULL&BEAR  PULLBEAR      JACKET SHIRT PANTS UNDERWEAR HAT  JACKET-SHIRT-PANTS   10
2   NIÑA  NINA        ZARA       ZARA          JEANS BIKINI DRESS SWEATER        JEANS-BIKINI-DRESS   13
```

The AJAX calls the php, and in the php I do a *pretty colum to normal colum* conversion in the database.

I think this is the only way to do what I want, isn't it? Any help or advice would be appreciated, and if you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. The values from the URL are just parameters, so you can use them to select rows from the database. When you parse your URL `http://myweb.com/nino/pullbear/jacket-shirt-pants/23` it would return something like

```
<?
$sex = 'nino';
$brand = 'pullbear';
$description = 'jacket-shirt-pants';
$age = '23';
?>
```

Then you can use that information to select something from the database. For simplicity I will concat the query, but make sure you do some [validation or use parameterized queries](http://myweb.com/nino/pullbear/jacket-shirt-pants/23)

```
<?
//WARNING: POSSIBLE UNSAFE EXAMPLE, DONT USE DIRECTLY IN PRODUCTION

$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE SEX_PRETTY='$sex' AND BRAND_PRETTY='$brand' AND DESCRIPTION_PRETTY='$description' AND AGE='$age'";

//now in your results you can use the `SEX`, `BRAND` and `DESCRIPION` columns to show information
?>
```

Keep in mind that if you want to uniquely identify a single product it would be best to create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the combined columns for `SEX_PRETTY`, `BRAND_PRETTY`,`DESCRIPTION_PRETTY` AND `AGE`.

Also since you are talking about using JSON keep in mind that not all special charactors are allowed, so you might need to encode them in the output. Check [json-character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583562/json-character-encoding)

Comment: Really thanks for the answer @Hugo Delsing. Well, I did this table only for the example becouse I thought is clearer than the one I have. I have another little answer: I have tables with rows which are repeated more or less 20 times each one. So I think in sepparate the _pretty colum_ in another table to don't have to repeat the information. So you think is good idea or it only obfuscate the structure?

Comment: I think the "SEX" should be a seperate table with the name and pretty name and then link the product to that table. The same goes for brands. So each brand is in the brands table once and the products link to that table.

Comment: As I said, this is not the real structure of the table which I work. But I understand your idea. Thanks for all, you helped me a lot. :)