# Alamofire request JSON

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I need to make a request to the following JSON

```
{
"usuario": {
    "nmeUsuario": "name",
    "username": "TestUsername",
    "senha": "46070d4bf934fb0d4b06d9e2c46e346944e322444900a435d7d9a95e6d7435f5"
},
"sistemaId": "2",
"contatos": [
    {
        "desContato": "test@test.com",
        "idTipoContato": {
            "idTipoContato": 1
        }
    }
]
```

}

I tried the following code

```
let senha = "46070d4bf934fb0d4b06d9e2c46e346944e322444900a435d7d9a95e6d7435f5"
let usuario = ["nmeUsuario":"name","username":"TestUsername","senha":senha]
let idContato = ["idContato":1]
let idTipoContato = ["idTipoContato":idContato]
let desContato = ["desContato":"test@test.com"]
let contato = [desContato, idTipoContato]
let parameters = ["usuario":usuario,"sistemaId":"2", "contatos":contato]
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).response { (request, response, data, error) in
        var datastring = NSString(data: request.HTTPBody!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println(datastring)
    }
```

however the json in request.HTTPBody looks like this:

```
{
"usuario": {
    "nmeUsuario": "name",
    "senha": "46070d4bf934fb0d4b06d9e2c46e346944e322444900a435d7d9a95e6d7435f5",
    "username": "TestUsername"
},
"sistemaId": "2",
"contatos": [
    {
        "desContato": "test@test.com"
    },
    {
        "idTipoContato": {
            "idContato": 1
        }
    }
]
```

}

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: why are you using utf8 encoding for json?

Comment: @longbow Why wouldn't he? http://stackoverflow.com/a/594881/1489885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want `contatos`'s array to contain a single dictionary, you need to declare your objects like this:

```
let senha = "46070d4bf934fb0d4b06d9e2c46e346944e322444900a435d7d9a95e6d7435f5"
let usuario = ["nmeUsuario":"name","username":"TestUsername","senha":senha]
let desContato = ["desContato":"test@test.com", "idTipoContato": ["idContato":1]]
let parameters = ["usuario":usuario,"sistemaId":"2", "contatos": [desContato]]
```

Result:

> {
>     "usuario" : {
>       "nmeUsuario" : "name",
>       "senha" : "46070d4bf934fb0d4b06d9e2c46e346944e322444900a435d7d9a95e6d7435f5",
>       "username" : "TestUsername"
>     },
>     "sistemaId" : "2",
>     "contatos" : [
>       {
>         "idTipoContato" : {
>           "idContato" : 1
>         },
>         "desContato" : "test@test.com"
>       }
>     ]
>   }