# how to use utf-8 with json in php file

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I'd like to output a utf8 json object in my php code:

```
 <?php
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $response= array();
 $product = array();
 $product["title"]="عنوان";
 $product["nim_body"]="بدنه";   
 $product["writer"]="نویسنده"; 
 array_push($response,$product);
 echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

and my output is like picture:

[image]

Comment: You *can* pass raw multibyte sequences, but unless you have a damned good reason to then you should not. Multibyte UTF8 sequences are not 7-bit safe and may cause your data to become corrupted in transit if you're not careful. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/594881/1064767

Answer (score 2):

Use [`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php).

> **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE** (integer)
>   Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.

There's no good reason to pretty print a json object unless you're printing into a file for example. If you need this for readability reasons, use a [browser extension](https://github.com/tulios/json-viewer) instead.

One more note; when responding with JSON objects, it's not enough to only output a valid object. You also need to set the content type header; `Content-Type: application/json`. You're setting this twice; once to `text/html` and then to `application/json`. Drop the former.