# MySQLI query result (multi-lines) to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, associative-array

I can not manage to see all the lines of my mysql query result returned as JSON Object using JSON_encode() php function. 
Here is my code :

```
$Sql_Query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$Sql_Query);
$ligne = array();
$bilan = array();

while ($rowr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ligne = array (
        "User_ID" => $rowr['User_ID']
    );
    $bilan[$ligne['User']] = $ligne[[
        ['User_ID'][$rowr['User_ID']]
    ]];
    array_push($bilan, $ligne);
}
echo json_encode($bilan, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

It returns me :

> {"":null,"0":{"User_ID":"1"},"1":{"User_ID":"19"},"2":{"User_ID":"78"},"3":{"User_ID":"79"},"4":{"User_ID":"85"},"5":{"User_ID":"86"},"6":{"User_ID":"87"},"7":{"User_ID":"88"},"8":{"User_ID":"91"},"9":{"User_ID":"92"},"10":{"User_ID":"93"},"11":{"User_ID":"94"},"12":{"User_ID":"95"},"13":{"User_ID":"96"},"14":{"User_ID":"97"},"15":{"User_ID":"98"},"16":{"User_ID":"99"},"17":{"User_ID":"100"},"18":{"User_ID":"101"},"19":{"User_ID":"102"},"20":{"User_ID":"103"},"21":{"User_ID":"104"},"22":{"User_ID":"105"},"23":{"User_ID":"106"},"24":{"User_ID":"107"},"25":{"User_ID":"108"},"26":{"User_ID":"109"},"27":{"User_ID":"110"},"28":{"User_ID":"111"},"29":{"User_ID":"112"},"30":{"User_ID":"113"},"31":{"User_ID":"114"},"32":{"User_ID":"115"},"33":{"User_ID":"116"}}

Now, I am trying to associate the other fields of each record in the json output. But when adding this to me code, there is no more output.

```
while ($rowr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ligne = array (
        "User_ID" => $rowr['User_ID'],
        "User_Nom" => $rowr['User_Nom']
    );      
    $bilan[$ligne['User']] = $ligne[[
        ['User_ID'][$rowr['User_ID']]
    ][
        ['User_Nom'][$rowr['User_Nom']]
    ]];
    array_push($bilan, $ligne);
}
echo json_encode($bilan, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

It seems like on numerical values can be displayed and not alpha characters.

Please help me mixing in the same output both numerical and alpha contents.

Thanks
Arnaud

Comment: There is no way that the code you claim is working could possibly produce the output you are suggesting it does. Can you please update with your actual code?

Comment: I don't understand this code `$bilan[$ligne['User']] = ...` is strange because `$ligne['User']` is not set to a value, it is not initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, since the orginal clean plan, because it was not working, I made too many modifications which finally added complexity where there is no need...

I found in php doc the possibility to learn more about the error generated when adding the other fields in the json conversion. json_last_error() was the key for understanding the issue.
So I added :

```
switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - Aucune erreur';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Profondeur maximale atteinte';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Inadéquation des modes ou underflow';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Erreur lors du contrôle des caractères';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Erreur de syntaxe ; JSON malformé';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Caractères UTF-8 malformés, probablement une erreur d\'encodage';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Erreur inconnue';
        break;
    }
```

This returns me a UTF-8 encoding issue. So I modified my code adding some

```
utf8_encode($rowr['Fieldname'])
```

First working solution is very near from @PaulH one's, just, in my specific case, I definetely have to add (utf8_encode()) statement :

```
    $Sql_Query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$Sql_Query);
    $ligne =array();
    $bilan = array();
    while ($rowr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $ligne = array ("User_ID" => $rowr['User_ID'],  
                        "User_Nom" => utf8_encode($rowr['User_Nom']),
                        "User_Prenom" =>utf8_encode($rowr['User_Prenom']));
        array_push ($bilan, $ligne);
    }
    echo json_encode($bilan, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

and it now displays all the fields, all the lines. But there were still some "é" transformed to "\u00e9". So [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583562/json-character-encoding-is-utf-8-well-supported-by-browsers-or-should-i-use-nu) put the final brick to the solution.

I modified :

> JSON_FORCED_OBJECT

to

> JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

as json_encode() parameter.

Finally, code delivering exactly what I want is the following :

```
$Sql_Query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$Sql_Query);
$bilan = array();
while ($rowr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ligne = array ("User_ID" => $rowr['User_ID'],  
                    "User_Nom" => utf8_encode($rowr['User_Nom']),
                    "User_Prenom" =>utf8_encode($rowr['User_Prenom']));
    array_push ($bilan, $ligne);
}
echo json_encode($bilan, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

$ligne['User'] is not initialised, could you try this:

```
while ($rowr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ligne = array (
        "User_ID" => $rowr['User_ID'],
        "User_Nom" => $rowr['User_Nom']
    );      
    array_push($bilan, $ligne);
}
echo json_encode($bilan, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

I tested it with this code

```
$result[] = ['User_ID' => 1, 'User_Nom' => 'Nom1'];
$result[] = ['User_ID' => 2, 'User_Nom' => 'Nom2'];
$result[] = ['User_ID' => 3, 'User_Nom' => 'Nom3'];
$bilan = [];
while ($rowr = array_pop($result)) {
    $ligne = array (
        "User_ID" => $rowr['User_ID'],
        "User_Nom" => $rowr['User_Nom']
    );
    array_push($bilan, $ligne);
}
echo json_encode($bilan, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

It provides this result:

> {"0":{"User_ID":3,"User_Nom":"Nom3"},"1":{"User_ID":2,"User_Nom":"Nom2"},"2":{"User_ID":1,"User_Nom":"Nom1"}}

Note the result has a different start, it does not contain

> "":null,

any more. This was the result of the strange `$bilan[undefined] = undefined` line

Answer (score 0):

**Converted to PHP >= 5.5 for clarity.**

I am guessing and making assumptions, but what else can I do? The main issue I see is that you may be tripping over your feet with the array syntax. It appears that you want to re-index the results by 'User_ID', which I assume is some string identifier found in each table record.

Modularized, in the procedural form ...

```
/*
    Assuming you are attempting to re-index by the 'User_ID' field
    of each record before encoding as JSON.
*/

function getDb($ip, $user, $password, $database) {
    $db = mysqli_connect($ip, $user, $password, $database);

    //error checking etc ...

    return $db;
}

function selectRecords(mysqli $db, $sql) {
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if (!$result) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("Database query (read) was unsuccessful!");
    }

    return $result;
}

function getUserRecords(mysqli $db) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM Users';
    return selectRecords($db, $query);
}

function reindexByField($newIndex, $userResults) {
    $reindexed = [];

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userResults)) {
        if (!isset($row[$newInded])) {
            throw new OutofBoundsException("The index '" . $newIndex . "' does not exist in the tested record");
        }

        $redindexed[$row[$newIndex]] = $row;
    }

    return $reindexed;
}

function getJsonFromArray(array $records) {
    $json = json_encode($records, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

    if (!$json) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("Records were not encoded into a JSON formatted string. Got boolean false, instead.");
    }

    return $json;
}
```

In the procedural form, then ...

```
try {
    $db = getDb($ip, $user, $password, $db); // Just pretend for a moment.
    echo getJsonFromArray(reindexByField('User_ID', getUserRecords($db));
} catch (e) {
    // Your handler code here.
} finally {
    mysqli_close($db);
}
```

An object-oriented approach can make your code more organized.