# How to show Rs Symbol (₹) in iOS push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

My backend team is sending the ₹ symbol in the iOS payload title as HTML to APNS. Which when received on the iOS device is not getting converted to the ₹ symbol. Could someone please assist as to how to get this thing done?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\u20B9` for INR symbol.

A sample APNS payload which works:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"\u20B9 Hello(4)","badge":1,"sound":"default"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try JSON ASCII escape for Unicode? Send \u00A3 for £ and \u20AC for €

[JSON character encoding - is UTF-8 well-supported by browsers or should I use numeric escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583562/json-character-encoding-is-utf-8-well-supported-by-browsers-or-should-i-use-nu)