# php mysql parsing json utf-8 encoding problems

Tags: php, mysql, json

My php code is below :

```
<?php

$HostName = "localhost";
$HostUser = "root";
$HostPass = "pass";
$DatabaseName = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM  demo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows >0) {

    while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       $tem = $row;
       $json = json_encode($tem);
    }
} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

I expect the output of like this :

```
[{"id":"1","name":"ami","phone":"এক"},{"id":"2","name":"tmi","phone":"দুই"}]
```

but the actual output is

```
[{"id":"1","name":"ami","phone":"\u0987\u0982\u09b2\u09cd\u09af\u09be\u09a8\u09cd\u09a1"},{"id":"2","name":"tmi","phone":"\u0987\u0982\u09b2\u09cd\u09af\u09be\u09a8\u09cd\u09a1"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get this output is because the data is actually stored that way in the database. It's the `json_encode` method that converts it to this representation. Once you decode it with any json decoder, you should get your unicode characters back.

This is further explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/594881/2232127

(To clarify: This is not a bug or a problem at all. It's intended and useful behavior which avoids encoding problems)